# Sharepoint Timer Service stopping without warning

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, timer-service

Need some expert advice so here is the scenario:

Start Sharepoint Timer v4 service with username/password.  All works fine.  At some point the timer service stops (nothing that I can see in ULS or Event log).  The strange thing is that I can't just simply restart the service.  I have to go in, reset the password to what it is supposed to be, and then it allows me to restart the timer service.  Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the account:

- has the dbcreator role on the db server
- securityadmin role on the db server
- db_owner role for all databases in the farm

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee924649.aspx